# Rails Rspec/Capybara feature spec asking me to install ImageMagick?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I am writing some integration specs that test forms for uploading user content to a site. I get the following error though I have ImageMagick installed and it is working perfectly in the development environment.

```
[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::Errors::CommandNotFoundError: Could not run the `identify` command. Please install ImageMagick.>
```

I know I could stub out ImageMagick as described [here](http://pivotallabs.com/stubbing-out-paperclip-imagemagick-in-tests/) however I would like to get it working without stubbing out the service. How do I make sure Rspec can access ImageMagick?

Answer (score 1):

I needed to add the Paperclip command path to the environments/test.rb file.

To do this I typed `which convert` in the terminal to get the ImageMagick path which was `/usr/local/bin/convert`. I used this info to insert the following line in the test environment file:

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/local/bin/"
```

Done